# MongoDB Aggregation - lookup pipeline is not returning correct document

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to join two collections. MQL is working fine in mongo compass but when i exported it into Golang, the api is returning incorrect data with correct arr length.

here is my go code

```
var query= bson.A{
bson.D{
    {"$addFields",
        bson.D{
            {"opStartDate",
                bson.D{
                    {"$dateFromString",
                        bson.D{
                            {"dateString",
                                bson.D{
                                    {"$concat",
                                        bson.A{
                                            "$indate",
                                            " ",
                                            "$intime",
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            {"format", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"},
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            {"opEndDate",
                bson.D{
                    {"$cond",
                        bson.A{
                            bson.D{
                                {"$ne",
                                    bson.A{
                                        "$outdate",
                                        "",
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            bson.D{
                                {"$dateFromString",
                                    bson.D{
                                        {"dateString",
                                            bson.D{
                                                {"$concat",
                                                    bson.A{
                                                        "$outdate",
                                                        " ",
                                                        "$outtime",
                                                    },
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                        {"format", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"},
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            time.Now(),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
bson.D{
    {"$lookup",
        bson.D{
            {"from", "transaction"},
            {"let",
                bson.D{
                    {"ophubname", "$hubname"},
                    {"inDateTime", "$opStartDate"},
                    {"outDateTime", "$opEndDate"},
                },
            },
            {"pipeline",
                bson.A{
                    bson.D{
                        {"$match",
                            bson.D{
                                {"$and",
                                    bson.A{
                                        bson.D{{"start", bson.D{{"$exists", true}}}},
                                        bson.D{{"stop", bson.D{{"$exists", true}}}},
                                        bson.D{{"stop", bson.D{{"$ne", ""}}}},
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    bson.D{
                        {"$match",
                            bson.D{
                                {"$expr",
                                    bson.D{
                                        {"$and",
                                            bson.A{
                                                bson.D{
                                                    {"$eq",
                                                        bson.A{
                                                            "$hubname",
                                                            "$$ophubname",
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                },
                                                bson.D{
                                                    {"$gte",
                                                        bson.A{
                                                            bson.D{
                                                                {"$convert",
                                                                    bson.D{
                                                                        {"input", "$start"},
                                                                        {"to", "date"},
                                                                        {"onError", ""},
                                                                    },
                                                                },
                                                            },
                                                            "$$inDateTime",
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                },
                                                bson.D{
                                                    {"$lte",
                                                        bson.A{
                                                            bson.D{
                                                                {"$convert",
                                                                    bson.D{
                                                                        {"input", "$stop"},
                                                                        {"to", "date"},
                                                                        {"onError", time.Now()},
                                                                    },
                                                                },
                                                            },
                                                            "$$outDateTime",
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            {"as", "transaction"},
        },
    },
},
```

}

cur, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), query)

i tried using mongo.Pipeline instead of bson.A - it didnt work

Comment: Hi, can you explain better your request? Please use a more readable example coz it's very hard to follow & understand, thanks!

Comment: the above query is working in mongo compass, but when i tried the same query by exporting it to go code from mongo compass, its not working(i.e, in the lookup incorrect hub_name are grouped but its showing correctly in mongo compass).

Its working now 
what i changed is
Instead of using for <cur.Next(context.TODO())>, i used <cur.All()>

Thanks